# Is there a Python 3.x debugger for embedded interpreter?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x

I've embedded python in a C++ application. Is there any graphical debugger that I can attach to debug scrips that run in the embedded console for Python 3.4?

Previously (when using Python 2.7) I've used Winpdb and attached the debugger with

```
import rpdb2; rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger(password)
```

but Winpdb doesn't work with wxPython Phoenix that is needed for Python 3.x.

I must load the debugger from inside the embedded interpreter since a lot of modules are only available there, so scripts can't be run outside that environment.

What alternatives are there to Winpdb for embedded debugging with GUI? Or is there an updated version of Winpdb that works with wxPython Phoenix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio) or PyDev on Eclipse Remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this official fork as version 2.0.0: [WinPDB Reborn](https://github.com/bluebird75/winpdb)

It can be installed with pip3:

```
pip3 install winpdb-reborn
```

I tested this with python 3.9 and could debug an embedded script inside a C++ application with boost-python on localhost.